# How do I link or copy/paste (&lock position) an excel drop down (vlookup) into a word doc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

How do I link or copy/paste (&lock position) an excel drop down (vlookup) into a word doc?

I have the excel file.  I created the list and then created my drop down using vlookup so that when I select "Port of NOLA" the next cell shows the address.  I can copy/paste special into word, but when I click the link, it opens the excel page, then I have to use the drop down to choose...which then returns the value to word.

I'm not entering 150 port names and addresses using word's drop down method...would take forever.  Anyway...hope that makes sense.  Please help.  I don't know how to do the cool stuff with these programs.  Thanks.

Comment: What link are you clicking? By address do you mean URL by any chance? maybe a screen cap of the XLSX and DOCX would be useful, you can upload those to http://imgur.com and link to them, someone with enough reputation will likely embed them for you

Comment: Read this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/731303/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-a-word-document/